# Can't seem to get subset() working in r

Tags: r, subset

Say I want to look at a subset whose age is 55 to 100, to look at their health care costs.

I've used:

```
Elders <- subset(midus, Age>= 55 | Age<100)
mean(Elders$Cost, na.rm=TRUE)
#78.8445
```

I understand this should give me the mean cost for people between 55 and 100.  In this case, it's 78.8445

Sounds great.  BUT, to check, I compare it to ages 95-100:

```
Elders2<-subset(midus,Age>=95 | Age<100)
mean(Elders2$Cost, na.rm=TRUE)
#78.8445
```

It seems very unlikely to me that these two subsets have identical means.  And I can't figure out what I did wrong to make it think that they do.  Anyone have any ideas?

Appreciate the help.  I've lurked stack overflow since starting this class and it's helped me immensely.

Comment: This seems less of a problem with `subset` and more of a problem in that the computer gave you *exactly* what you asked for instead of what you intended.

Comment: @DWin in this case I think it's much simpler. x > a | x < b (with a<b) does **not** subset the numeric set where x, a and b are defined. Regardless if a is 50 or 95, he did the mean of the whole sample. It's more a math problem than coding.

Answer (score 3):

I find using the `[` syntax less confusing than `subset`. You haven't given a sample of data to help us but something like this should work. And surely you mean `AND` (&) rather than `OR` (|) in your code?

```
Elders <- midus[midus$Age >= 55 & midus$Age < 100, ]
```

Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset?rq=1) and the answers.

Comment: Truthfully, I don't understand why, but using [] instead solved the problem.  Thanks a lot SlowLearner.

Comment: "And surely you mean AND (&) rather than OR (|) in your code" is why this code worked and your code didn't.

Comment: @ChrisKilbourn the problem is not `[]` nor `subset`. you used the wrong logical condition. You did the mean of the **whole** table in both cases. have you tried `mean(midus$Cost, na.rm=TRUE)`?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using `subset`

```
> # generating some data
> set.seed(1)
> midus <- data.frame(ID=1:50,
+                     Age=sample(20:100, 50, TRUE), 
+                     Cost=rnorm(50, 100, 3))
> 
> Elders <- subset(midus, Age>= 55 & Age<100) # subseting
> mean(Elders$Cost) 
[1] 100.2068
> 
> Elders2<-subset(midus, Age>=95 & Age<100)
> mean(Elders2$Cost)
[1] 98.78458
```

As you can see, just changing `|` to `&` gives what you want. This is because you want those values of `Age` between 55 AND 100 (not including 100), so you need to use the `&` operator.